# Google Cloud Platform Push-To-Deploy fails: `xslt-config: not found`

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to set up the Google Cloud Platform's [push-to-deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) for one of my appengine applications. In order to execute my unit tests, I need to install lxml. This requires that the build machine has development packages of libxml2 and libxslt installed. I ssh'd to the compute vm and installed those packages and it still fails. I am assuming that the node `Python: cloud-dev-python` is a different machine and I do not have access to it to install those packages.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

```
Started by user User Name
Building remotely on cloud-dev-python in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/JoshTesting
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
...snip...
Installing app_lib.
Getting distribution for 'lxml==2.3.5'.
unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
Building lxml version 2.3.5.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt 
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occurred when trying to install lxml 2.3.5. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing app_lib.
  Getting distribution for 'lxml==2.3.5'.
Error: Couldn't install: lxml 2.3.5
+ echo Buildout failed. Check the logs and try again...
Buildout failed. Check the logs and try again...
+ exit 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: Forgot to add the logs output. I edited it in place

Comment: Thank you.  I wish I knew how to help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it in a roundabout manner.

Google's VM uses docker to house a few build executors so I needed to connect to the `cloud-dev-python` instance and install a few packages on it with `apt-get`.

I ssh'd to the host VM and executed the following:

```
root@bitnami-jenkins$ CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps | grep cloud-dev-python | awk '{print $1}')
root@bitnami-jenkins$ sudo docker exec -i -t $CONTAINER_ID bash
root@<container id>:/$ apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y build-essential libz-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

Comment: I can't yet. 21 more hours before I am allowed to.